# HTML table to proper excel table Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am pretty new at Python and struggling with printing the web scraping data to beautiful excel table.
Here is a table I am trying to **scrape** and replicate in Python:
[HTML Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZjRu.png).

Here is how HTML page looks like:

```
</div>
    <section id="first" style="display:none" aria-label="Power situation graph section">
        <div class="gridModule-2up">
            <div class="prognos_controls hidden" data-proggraph="1">
                Show data for:
                <button value="1" onclick="this.blur();" type="button" class="btn  btn--secondary prognosdaybutton"><span class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></span> Yesterday</button>
                <button value="2" onclick="this.blur();" type="button" class="btn  btn--tertiary prognosdaybutton"><span class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></span> Today</button>
                <button value="3" onclick="this.blur();" type="button" class="btn  btn--secondary prognosdaybutton"><span class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></span> Tomorrow</button>
            </div>
            <table summary="Consumption" id="prognos_datatable_total" class="prognos_datatable scrollable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                                <th data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]"></th>
                                <th data-sheets-value="[null,2,'17/02/2020']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]" scope="col">2020-02-17</th>
                                <th data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]"></th>
                                <th data-sheets-value="[null,2,'18/02/2020']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]" scope="col">2020-02-18</th>
                                <th data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]"></th>
                                <th data-sheets-value="[null,2,'19/02/2020']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]" scope="col">2020-02-19</th>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th caldata-sheets-value="[null,2,'Timme']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]" scope="col">Hour</th>
                                <th data-sheets-value="[null,2,'F\u00f6rbrukning']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]" scope="col">Consumption</th>
                                <th data-sheets-value="[null,2,'Prognos']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]" scope="col">Forecast</th>
                                <th data-sheets-value="[null,2,'F\u00f6rbrukning']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]" scope="col">Consumption</th>
                                <th data-sheets-value="[null,2,'Prognos']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]" scope="col">Forecast</th>
                                <th data-sheets-value="[null,2,'F\u00f6rbrukning']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]" scope="col">Consumption</th>
                                <th data-sheets-value="[null,2,'Prognos']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]" scope="col">Forecast</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-sheets-value="[null,2,'00-01']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]" scope="col">
                            00-01
                        </th>

                            <td data-sheets-value="[null,2,'15544']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">15&#160;544</td>
                            <td class="alert_1" data-sheets-value="[null,2,'15143']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">15&#160;143</td>
                            <td data-sheets-value="[null,2,'15669']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">15&#160;669</td>
                            <td class="alert_1" data-sheets-value="[null,2,'15869']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">15&#160;869</td>
                            <td data-sheets-value="[null,2,'-']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">-</td>
                            <td class="alert_1" data-sheets-value="[null,2,'16422']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">16&#160;422</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-sheets-value="[null,2,'01-02']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]" scope="col">
                            01-02
                        </th>

                            <td data-sheets-value="[null,2,'15238']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">15&#160;238</td>
                            <td class="alert_1" data-sheets-value="[null,2,'15052']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">15&#160;052</td>
                            <td data-sheets-value="[null,2,'15509']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">15&#160;509</td>
                            <td class="alert_1" data-sheets-value="[null,2,'15366']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">15&#160;366</td>
                            <td data-sheets-value="[null,2,'-']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">-</td>
                            <td class="alert_1" data-sheets-value="[null,2,'16176']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">16&#160;176</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-sheets-value="[null,2,'02-03']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]" scope="col">
                            02-03
                        </th>

                            <td data-sheets-value="[null,2,'15250']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">15&#160;250</td>
                            <td class="alert_1" data-sheets-value="[null,2,'15135']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">15&#160;135</td>
                            <td data-sheets-value="[null,2,'15576']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">15&#160;576</td>
                            <td class="alert_1" data-sheets-value="[null,2,'15501']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">15&#160;501</td>
                            <td data-sheets-value="[null,2,'-']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">-</td>
                            <td class="alert_1" data-sheets-value="[null,2,'16124']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]">16&#160;124</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-sheets-value="[null,2,'03-04']" data-sheets-numberformat="[null,1]" scope="col">
                            03-04
                        </th>.............
```

Here is the code I used:

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = 'myURLlink'

response = requests.get(url) 

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

extract = soup.select("table")[1]

table = [[item.text for item in row_data.select("th,td")]
                for row_data in extract.select("tr")]

for item in table:
    print(' '.join(item))
```

This is how my output looks with this code: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m9Hn.png).

How can I create a normal data frame from this that I can then export to Excel?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of escape characters.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("sample.html", "r") as f:

    contents = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')
    extract = soup.find("table")

    # added strip() to remove leading and trailing characters
    table = [[item.text.strip() for item in row_data.select("th,td")]
                    for row_data in extract.select("tr")]

    for item in table:
        print(' '.join(item))
```

Check output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdKiI.png)

Comment: You could remove the useless imports (`csv`, `lxml.html`, `requests`, `pandas`) from your code snippet. Along with commented lines that do not provide value.

Comment: Thank you Kunal! It helped a lot. Is it possible to create a data frame out of this result?

Comment: Katya, yes it is possible. Just convert list to dataframe :- df = pd.DataFrame(table)

Comment: and yes than df.to_csv("demo.csv", index=False)

Answer (score 1):

Try going with pandas here. It uses beautifulsoup under the hood. I can't test it on your URL since you havent provided one.

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'myURLlink'
df = pd.read_html(url)[1]

df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
print (df.to_string())
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply. I get a CSV file with some weird symbols inside. Maybe you could take a look? The url is: https://www.svk.se/en/national-grid/the-control-room/ . Thank you!

Comment: @Katya, change line to: `df.to_csv('file.csv',  encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)`